# Use a prior triangular distribution in rethinking - R

Tags: r, rstan

I’m using the rethinking package in R to make a simple linear model. In the folowing code  I use a prior normal distribution for the dependent variable and everything works good.

```
library(rethinking)
col <- alist(
  courework_n ~ dnorm(mean,0.2),
  mean <- a + b*result_n + c,
  a ~ dnorm(0,10),
  b ~ dnorm(0,10),
  c ~ dnorm(0,10)
)
colmap <- map( col , data.frame(data) )
```

But when I use a package for triangular distribution which is not supported directly by R, I get the following error

> **Error in map(col, data.frame(data)) : unused argument (log = TRUE)**

This is the code for defining the model with the triangle distribution

```
install.packages("RTriangle") 
library(triangle)

col <- alist(
  courework_n ~ dtriangle(0,1,mode),
  moda <- a + b*result_n + c,
  a ~ dnorm(0,10),
  b ~ dnorm(0,10),
  c ~ dnorm(0,10)
)

col_map <- map( col , data.frame(data) )
```

Comment: Triangular priors can have the same  priors have the same issue with unintended bias due to boundary position as uniform priors on an interval.  If mass would've extended beyond the boundary, the boundary pushes it away from the boundary pushing the posterior estimate away from the boundary.  So even if the unbounded estimate would've been near the boundary, the existence of the boundary pushes it away from the boundary, which is usually unintended for these kinds of priors (which are usually motivated by wanting to identify rough interval of solution and highest density point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `dtriangle` distribution doesn't incorporate a `log` parameter as is expected of probability distribution functions in R/by `rethinking`.

You can hack the `dtriangle` function as follows:

- first `dput(dtriangle,file="my_dtriangle.R")` to save the function code to a file
- edit the first line to read

```
 my_dtriangle <- function (x, a = 0, b = 1, c = (a + b)/2, log=FALSE)
```

- change the last line of code (`return(apply(params, 1, dTest))`) to:

```
 res <- apply(params, 1, dTest)
 if (log) return(log(res)) else return(res)
```

- `source("my_dtriangle.R")` to redefine the function in your workspace

It's conceivable that you will run into further technical problems using a function that has compact support (i.e., has zero likelihood outside of a restricted range of values)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great trick that can be used for lots of other things, I appreciate too much your help. Anyway you were right, now I’m having a problem because the dtriangle function requires the x value for its computation (as all the others d-distributions in R) but I supposed that when using ej: dnorm and omitting the x value, rethinking uses another file of the stats family functions.

Comment: Would it be possible to just write a wrapper function using `...` and not have to cut-and-paste?  When you have a log scale, you can often more robustly do your calculations on the log scale directly.